# Get selected button in navbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page that has 2 jqm navbars. When the user clicks a "Next" button at the bottom of the page, I want to get the selected button for each individual navbar. Ideally something like:

var nav1Value = $('#Navbar1.ui-btn-active').text();
var nav2Value = $('#Navbar2.ui-btn-active').text();

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to provide the best answer without looking at your code. But based on what you questions says it'd be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var nav1Value, nav2Value;

  $('.nextButton').on('click', function(){
    nav1Value = $('#Navbar1.ui-btn-active').text();
    nav2Value = $('#Navbar2.ui-btn-active').text();
   });
});
```